# Ajax error when using sqlite plugin in phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, sqlite, cordova

I'm making a phonegap app which reads json data from external server via ajax. I need to load and save data in a sqlite database. Native sqlite generates an callback function error about which I asked on stackoverflow but didn't get any answer.  I decided then to use a sqlite plugin but when I use it in my app, error function defined in ajax executes. Without plugin, it works well. Please tell me how I can use sqlite with or without plugin without any error. Here's the code I'm using:

```
              var DB = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "Posts_DB.db"});
              var BASE_URI = "https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1.1/sites/smushbits.com/";
         var POST_OFFSET = 0;


             function getPosts() {
          $.mobile.loading('show');

            $.ajax({
                    url: BASE_URI + "posts",
                     type: "GET",
                       dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                     "number": 10,
                      "offset": POST_OFFSET,
                       "order": "DESC"
                      },
                  error: function() {
                   alert("An error occured.");
                    },
                   success: function(response) {
                   $.each(response.posts, function(index, data) {
                   $('<li><a href="#single" data-transition="slide" id="'+data.ID+'"><h1>'+data.title+'</h1><p>'+getDays(data.date)+'</p></a></li>').appendTo('#latest-list');
                   $(document).on("click", "#"+data.ID, function() {
                showPost(data.title, data.date, data.content, data.URL);
                   });
              });
                $('#latest-list').listview('refresh');
             $.mobile.loading("hide");
                }
              });
         POST_OFFSET+=10;
        }
          document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        function onDeviceReady() {
        $(document).ready( function() {
        DB.transaction(createTableDB, errorCB, successCB);
         getPosts();
        });
        }

           function createTableDB(tx) {
             tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Posts(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Title TEXT NOT NULL, Date TEXT NOT NULL, Content TEXT NOT NULL, Link TEXT NOT NULL)');
              }

           function populateDB(tx) {
               var title = document.getElementById('entry-title').innerHTML;
              var date = document.getElementById('entry-date').innerHTML;
              var content = document.getElementById('entry').innerHTML;
               var url = document.getElementById('browser').getAttribute('href');
               tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Posts(Title,Date,Content,Link) VALUES(?,?,?,?)', [title, date, content, url] );
               }


              function errorCB(err) {
                alert("Error processing SQL: "+err.message);
               }


                function successCB() {
                   DB.transaction(queryDB, errorCB);
                }


                 function queryDB(tx){
                   tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Posts', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
                  }

             function querySuccess(tx,result){
               $('#saved-articles-list').empty();
              for( var index = 0; index < result.rows.length; index++) {
                     var row = result.rows.item(index);
                    $('#saved-articles-list').append('<li><a id="'+row['id']+'" data-transition="slide" href="#single"><h1 class="ui-li-heading">'+row['Title']+'</h1><p class="ui-li-desc">'+getDays(row['Date'])+'</p></a></li>');
                   $(document).on("click", row['id'], function() {
                    showPost(row['Title'], row['Date'], row['Content'], row['Link']);
             });
           }

           $('#saved-articles-list').listview("refresh");
       }
```

Config.xml:

```
           <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
           <widget xmlns   = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
              xmlns:gap   = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
             xmlns:android   = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             id          = "com.smushbits.app"
             versionCode = "10" 
             version     = "1.0.0" >

             <!-- versionCode is optional and Android only -->

            <name>TestApp</name>

             <description>
              Test app
            </description>

              <author href="https://smushbits.com/about" email="xyz@gmail.com">
               Vishal Singh 
                </author>
                 <access origin="*" />
               <platform name="android" >
             <preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
             <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
            </platform>
           <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network" />
            <plugin name="com.indigoway.cordova.whitelist.whitelistplugin" source="pgb" />
         <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="1.1.0" />
        <plugin name="io.litehelpers.cordova.sqlite" spec="0.7.10" source="pgb" />
        <plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing" spec="5.0.7" />
         <allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
         <allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
          <allow-navigation href="data:*" />
          <allow-intent href="*" />
           <icon src="icon.png" />
            <splash src="splash.png" />
            </widget>
```

Index.html:

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>SmushBits</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile.min.css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/app.css" >
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="phonegap.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload="init()">
<div id="home" data-role="page" data-theme="a">
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
<a href="#navpanel1" class="ui-btn ui-btn-left ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-icon-notext ui-icon-bars"></a>
<h1>SmushBits</h1>
<a href="#search" data-transition="slidedown" class="ui-btn ui-btn-right ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-icon-notext ui-icon-search"></a>
</div> 
<div data-role="content">
<ul data-role="listview" id="latest-list">
</ul>
</div>
</div>


<div id="single" data-role="page" data-theme="a">
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
<a href="#navpanel5" class="ui-btn ui-btn-left ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-icon-notext ui-icon-bars"></a>
<h1>SmushBits</h1>
<a href="#search" data-transition="slidedown" class="ui-btn ui-btn-right ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-icon-notext ui-icon-search"></a>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
<h1 id="entry-title"></h1>
<div id="save-complete"></div>
<h4 id="entry-date"></h4>
<div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
<a id="save-post" class="ui-btn ui-icon-heart">Save</a><a id="share" class="ui-btn ui-icon-star">Share</a><a href="" id="browser" class="ui-btn ui-icon-navigation">Browse</a></div>
<div id="entry"></div>
</div>
</div>


<div id="saved-articles" data-role="page" data-theme="a">
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
<a href="#navpanel4" class="ui-btn ui-btn-left ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-icon-notext ui-icon-bars"></a>
<h1>SmushBits</h1>
<a href="#search" data-transition="slidedown" class="ui-btn ui-btn-right ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-icon-notext ui-icon-search"></a>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
<ul data-role="listview" id="saved-articles-list" data-split-icon="delete">
</ul>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will help you create a sample sqlite database that you can use to create, edit, delete, and update your database without the need of sqlite plugin.

table.js (your javascript file)

```
var scroll = new iScroll('wrapper', {
 vScrollbar : false,
 hScrollbar : false,
 hScroll : false
});



        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        var currentRow;
        // Populate the database
        //
        function populateDB(tx) {



            }

        // Query the database
        //
        function queryDB(tx) {
            tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM DEMO', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
        }

        function searchQueryDB(tx) {
            tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM DEMO where name like ('%"+ document.getElementById("txtName").value + "%')",
                    [], querySuccess, errorCB);
        }
        // Query the success callback
        //
        function querySuccess(tx, results) {
            var tblText='<table id="t01"><tr><th>ID</th> <th>Name</th> <th>Number</th></tr>';
            var len = results.rows.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                var tmpArgs=results.rows.item(i).id + ",'" + results.rows.item(i).name
                        + "','" + results.rows.item(i).number+"'";
                tblText +='<tr onclick="goPopup('+ tmpArgs + ');"><td>' + results.rows.item(i).id +'</td><td>'
                        + results.rows.item(i).name +'</td><td>' + results.rows.item(i).number +'</td></tr>';
            }
            tblText +="</table>";
            document.getElementById("tblDiv").innerHTML =tblText;
        }

        //Delete query
        function deleteRow(tx) {
          tx.executeSql('DELETE FROM DEMO WHERE id = ' + currentRow, [], queryDB, errorCB);
        }

        // Transaction error callback
        //
        function errorCB(err) {
            alert("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
        }

        // Transaction success callback
        //
        function successCB() {
            var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
            db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB);
        }

         // Cordova is ready
        //
        function onDeviceReady() {
            var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
            db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
        }

        //Insert query
        //
        function insertDB(tx) {


 var sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO( "+ " id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ,"  + "name VARCHAR(50), "
   + "number INT)";
 tx.executeSql(sql);

 var Name =document.getElementById("txtName").value;
 var Number = document.getElementById("txtNumber").value;
 tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO DEMO (name,number) VALUES ('"+ Name +"','"+ Number +"' )");


        }

        function goInsert() {


             var Name = document.getElementById("txtName").value;
             var Number = document.getElementById("txtNumber").value;


            var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
            db.transaction(insertDB, errorCB, successCB);


        }

        function goSearch() {
            var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
            db.transaction(searchQueryDB, errorCB);
        }

        function goDelete() {
             var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
             db.transaction(deleteRow, errorCB);
             document.getElementById('qrpopup').style.display='none';
        }

        //Show the popup after tapping a row in table
        //
        function goPopup(row,rowname,rownum) {
            currentRow=row;
            document.getElementById("qrpopup").style.display="block";
            document.getElementById("editNameBox").value = rowname;
            document.getElementById("editNumberBox").value = rownum;
        }

        function editRow(tx) {
            tx.executeSql('UPDATE DEMO SET name ="'+document.getElementById("editNameBox").value+
                    '", number= "'+document.getElementById("editNumberBox").value+ '" WHERE id = '
                    + currentRow, [], queryDB, errorCB);
        }
        function goEdit() {
            var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
             db.transaction(editRow, errorCB);
              document.getElementById('qrpopup').style.display='none';
         }
```

index.html (note that i make reference to table.js here bcos i created seperate file both)

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 

    <head>
        <title></title>

        <style type="text/css">

input[type='text'] {
       border: 1px solid black;
       width: 200px;
       margin-left: 10px;
}
table {
    width:100%;
}
table, th, td {
              border: 1px solid black;
              border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;
}
table#t01 tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #eee;
}
table#t01 tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color:#fff;
}
table#t01 th    {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
button {
    margin: 10px;
    font: bold 13px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, clean, sans-serif !important;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), -2px 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #BE3E76;
    border-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: visible;
}

button:active {
    background-position: 0 -100px;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
}

#qrpopup {
    position:fixed;z-index:9999;background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0,0.9);width:100%; height:100%;display:none;
}


</style>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/tables.js"></script>    
    </head>

<body>
    <h1>TABLES </h1>
    <p>Open Database</p>
    <div id="qrpopup" > //The hidden div tag for implementing the popup
            <hr/>
            <input type="text" id="editNameBox"><br>
            <input type="text" id="editNumberBox"><br>
            <button onclick="goDelete()">Delete</button>
            <button onclick="goEdit()">Edit</button>
            <button onclick="document.getElementById('qrpopup').style.display='none';">Discard</button>
    </div>

    <div>
        Name<input type="text" value="Name" id="txtName">
        Number<input type="text" value="123" id="txtNumber"><hr/>
    </div>

    <div style="text-align: center">
        <button onclick="goInsert()">Insert</button>
        <button onclick="goSearch()">Search</button>
        <button onclick="successCB()">Show All</button>
        <a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.wikipedia.org','_self','location=yes')">Wikipedia (webview)</a>

    </div>


      <div id="tblDiv"></div>

  </body>
  </html>
```

This will solve your problem; just do a little editing to make it work for your project.

Answer (score 0):

i can help with using sqlite without plugin but your  questions is not clear enough to know the solution am to provide.kindly explain what operations you want with sqlite that is not using plugin

Comment: I'm want to store the article which I'm loading from my server through ajax. How can I do that?

Comment: Ok @vishal ,i will give u an example to use when am on pc.also supply me with your index.html details

Comment: I have added the source code of my index.html above.

Comment: it worked without error. Thanks! :)  I want to ask one more question whether it is necessary to set database transaction in deviceready callback function?

Comment: yes it is necessary and very important that it is set ..and make sure that your Javascript statement and file are placed after closing the body tag ,to avoid bringing undefined database when deploying on real device,Any way your database will work correctly but the undefined it will be prompting will pose to be a mess.Also i want you to help me post  your project source code when you finish it and apk file or anything that will be useful. do you use netbeans to develop your cordova application or what ide do you use?

Comment: Okay. I'll post it. I don't use netbeans. I'm using phonegap build currently.

Comment: Am also using phonegap but cordova latest own.Is your inappbrowser working? If yes lemme know how you make it work

Comment: Yeah! It's working. I use the following: `window.open(encodeURI(url), "_system", "location=no")`

Comment: if you use `_system` ,you are asking it to open the link with the phone browser.rather you use  `_blank ` to make it open in the app using inappbrowser. hope you have test it on android to see what am saying or else maybe you have other code to make it not user phone browser.

Comment: I wanted the links to open in phone browser. :) Actually I'm building the app that will read blogs from my website and making links open in phone's browser seems to be a good idea in this case.

Comment: ok anyway ,you are the one to decide how your app will look and operate.just let me know when you are done and share your project source code.happy coding!